# Running SQL against the source in Informatica and exporting results to a target table

Tags: sql, etl, informatica

Using Informatica designer, is there a way to run a complex SELECT statement as-is against a source database, and workflow it into a target table?

For example, SQL Server Integration Services makes it really easy to create source/target connections, paste your source SQL, and map the results to the target table.  When the package is run, SQL runs against the source, and results are dumped into the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to create a source definition with ports that reflect the columns in your SELECT statement and override the generated query with yours by putting it into the `SQL Query` field of the Source Qualifier transformation.

Then link the port to the target, generate the session and workflow, configure the connections and your're done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Informatica generates a query of its own for the columns which you propagate from Source Qualififer and you can override this Query at 2 levels:
1. Mapping Level: In source qualifier you can override it and you can validate the query
2. Session Level: In session you can use SQL QUERY column for your source to overrirde the default query and validate that as well. Also at session level you can pass this query as a parameter giving you flexibility to change source query as and when you desire